# Пространсто имен Psr in Slim Php

Tags: php, composer, namespace, slim

Я установил Slim через Composer и попытался выполнить первый же скрипт [который выводит имя](https://www.slimframework.com/)

Он не работал, я начал ковырять и не нашел там такого пространства имен Psr

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
```

Я заглядывал в composer.json и в моем компе и на гитхаб slim

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
```

Объясните что это Psr и откуда оно взялось

Comment: из папки Vendor

Comment: Его там нет и кидает ошибку. Не идет в комплекте со слимом что странно как по мне.

Comment: Укажите команду, которой вы установили slim

Comment: Через композер установил. Короче нужно использовать и установаливать PSR отдельно.

Comment: composer install делали? Подключали `vendor` автозагрузку?